# MS Access VBA check if Confirm option is checked

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

Is there a way in VBA to check if a user has the Confirm options on? When performing some actions, these options need to be on. The reason being, the 
`Form_AfterDelConfirm(status As Integer)` will not fire if these options are off.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Application.GetOption "OptionName"` and `Application.SetOption "OptionName", value` methods. The difficulty in using these is knowing what `OptionName` string you exactly need. In your case the corresponding strings are:

```
Application.SetOption "Confirm Action Queries", True
Application.SetOption "Confirm Document deletions", True
Application.SetOption "Confirm Record Changes", True
```

[Source for the strings in question.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/229802/how-to-use-setoption-to-disable-warning-messages-in-an-access-applicat)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I was looking for!

Comment: @Kevin Glad I could help. :)